# Why is my code entering the if statement when the conditions aren't met?

Tags: c++

Using this code to try and complete code academies challenge to make a program that redacts target words but its doing something unexpected.

main.cpp

```cpp
int main() {
  std::string word = "broccoli";
  std::string phrase = "This phrase is broccoli!";

  censure(word, phrase);

  std::cout << phrase << "\n";
}
```

functions.hpp

```cpp
void censure(std::string &targetword, std::string &input);
```

functions.cpp

```cpp
void censure(std::string &targetword, std::string &input) {

  std::string asterisk = "*";

  for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    if((input[i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5,i+6,i+7] == targetword[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])) {
      input[i + 0] = asterisk[0];
      input[i + 1] = asterisk[0];
      input[i + 2] = asterisk[0];
      input[i + 3] = asterisk[0];
      input[i + 4] = asterisk[0];
      input[i + 5] = asterisk[0];
      input[i + 6] = asterisk[0];
      input[i + 7] = asterisk[0];
    }
  }
}
```

it should be returning "this phrase is ********!" but instead its returning "This ********s *********!"

ive tried sliding the math around some but im honestly not sure whats causing the problem. my idea here is that it checks the input from left to right 8 characters at a time so 0-7, 1-8, 2-9, etc etc. and then if it finds a set of 8 that matches the characters in the target word it gets changed to asteriks. but for some reason its just randomly chaning things.

EDIT: figured it out. my if statement was only checking to see if ANY of the characters matched their counterparts, and so was triggering on the "I" in is. will have to use separate && statements from now on.

Comment: `input[i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5,i+6,i+7] == targetword[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` who told you that you can compare arrays this way?

Comment: Because the comma operator in C++ doesn't do what you think it does, at all.

Comment: `input[i + 0]` is a character. `asterisk[0]` Also a character. Since you just want characters here, save yourself some trouble and make `asterisk` a `char`. `const char asterisk = '*';` and then `input[i + 0] = asterisk;`, etc...

Comment: In order to find the first occurrance of a substring inside a string, you can use the standard library function [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: Side note: Don't edit solutions into answers. Solutions go in Answers. Side note to the side note: *my if statement was only checking to see if ANY of the characters matched their counterparts* is not true. You really owe it to yourself [to read up on what the comma operator does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) before you accidentally shoot yourself in the foot again.

Comment: Beginners and not only beginners must enable compiler warnings. You would see `warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect`.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator allows to execute many *things* and the return value is the last part. So here your *magic* test just boils down to:

```
if((input[i+7] == targetword[7])) {
    ...
```

As your sentence contains to `i` letters, you erase twice 7 characters. You'd better use the [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method of `std::string` here...